# Facebook Objective C to Swift 4

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am trying to implement facebook login using Swift 4

Facebook docs covers how to implement the facebook login button for the view controller but it does not cover how to set up the Appdelegate using swift

Can someone please convert this Objective C code to Swift

Or place a URL Link to docs that would help me convert it myself

```
//  AppDelegate.m
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

  [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
  // Add any custom logic here.
  return YES;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
            openURL:(NSURL *)url 
            options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {

  BOOL handled = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
    openURL:url
    sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
    annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]
  ];
  // Add any custom logic here.
  return handled;
}
```

Comment: This isn't a free code translation service. Please make an attempt to write your own Swift code. You can see what APIs to use in the Objective-C code. Update your question with your attempted Swift code and clearly explain what issues you are having.

Comment: Or place a URL Link to docs that would help me convert it myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are looking for this

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)           
        return true
    }
```

**And**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any])  -> Bool {
      return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String!, annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

import FacebookCore

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?



    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
        return true
    }


    @available(iOS 9.0, *)
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
        return SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, open: url, options: options)
    }


    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {

    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {

    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

        AppEventsLogger.activate(application)
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {

    }


}
```